# Comparing theano vs tensorflow function speed, how can I make tensorflow function faster?

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

OS: windows 10
procesor: core i7-6700

python 3.7 using anaconda

theano version 1.0.4       installed using: conda install theano pygpu

tensorflow version 2.1.0   installed using: pip install tensorflow

Both are running using cpu

I'm rewriting some of my code from theano to tensorflow and I find that the performance in tensorflow is not as fast as theano so I must be missing something that causes the tensorflow code to be slower.

below is sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time


#define tensorflow function
@tf.function
def tf_mean(data):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(data, axis=0)

#define theano function
tdata = T.dmatrix('tdata')
tmean = T.mean(tdata, axis=0)
theano_mean = function([tdata], tmean)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(1234)
    randomdata = np.random.random((3000,10))

    #run first time to warm up
    check_th = theano_mean(randomdata)
    check_tf = tf_mean(randomdata)


    # run each 10000 times
    start = time()
    for i in range(10000):
        theano_mean(randomdata)
    thtime = time()-start
    print('theano', thtime )

    start = time()
    for i in range(10000):
        tf_mean(randomdata)
    tftime = time()-start
    print('tensorflow', tftime )

    print('ratio', tftime / thtime)
```

output:
theano 0.4887216091156006

tensorflow 2.4310362339019775

ratio 4.9742761289013275

So theano is around 5 times faster than tensorflow it seems. How can I make tensorflow code above faster at least on par with theano?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Theano is much faster than Tensorflow when running on a CPU. Tensorflow only runs faster than Theano if you have multiple GPUs.